# Slider vs window width

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/57wm5dy7/3/

I first click "run" in jsfiddle and my base/start width is `min-width:900px` media query and here the slider works without issues...

...but then I resize the window MANUALLY WITH MY MOUSE into smaller max-width 700px media query

then I click next button (right arrow)

the slide width being offseted will be taken from `min-width:900px` media query (slide width 700px) even though I am inside smaller `max-width 700px` (slide width 500px).
I want to make the next/previous buttons when clicked to execute the width of the .c-testimonial of the media query I am currently in. No matter how many times I resize the window between 2 media queries.

```
@media screen and  (max-width:700px) {

  .c-testimonials {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 700px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align:center;
        padding:70px 0;
          &:before {
              content: '';
              position:absolute;
              top:0;
              bottom:0;
              z-index:-1;
              width:100vw;
              left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
              background-color: #f8f8f8;
          }    
          &__mask {
              margin:0 auto;
              position: relative;
              overflow:hidden;
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be consistent with using the same media queries - you once use `max-width` and then `min-width` which causes the problems. One rule is reused for everything lower than 900px and another one for everything higher than 700px so you have a conflict in between these 200px :)

The recommended approach in my opinion would be:

- Write a default behaviour
- Write a specific code for `max-width: 900px`
- Write a specific code for `max-width: 700px` that will overload previous one

Or another approach - the opposite one - starting with the smaller one and using `min-width`.

As a guide, you can check how the most popular `grid` libraries do it (e.g. Bootstrap grid system). Then tend not to mix `max-width` and `min-width` as these overlap each other and usually pose unexpected results.

Another thing - you have two breakpoints in your CSS (900px and 700px) but only one breakpoint in your code...

This is updated version of your code (still has some errors, but the containers is slided properly). It should be a good point for future improvements: https://jsfiddle.net/57wm5dy7/4/

*Side note: please try to reuse your code in a better way - a lot of the code in the snippet was duplicated without need and hence was less readable - please check the blocks I moved to a global context.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is no 200px conflict...max-width: 700px means width from 0px to 700px whereas min-width:900px means width from 900px upwards

Comment: So, essentially, you still have a gap between 700px and 900px and this is the reason layout is messed up. I'd still recommend cascading the media queries, as I did in the modified jsfiddle.